# IsolatedStorageException sometimes following a disk-full condition?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I'm designing an API. Currently I'm trying to safely handle a condition where we run out of disk space. Basically, we have a series of files holding some data. When the disk is full, when we go to write another data file, it will of course throw an error. At this point, we delete a single file(loop through file list from oldest to newest and retry after we successfully delete a file). Then, we retry writing the file. Repeat that process until the file is written without error.

Now the fun part. All of this happens concurrently. Like, at some point there are 8 threads doing this at once. This makes things extra interesting, and has lead to an odd error.

Here is the code

```
    public void Save(string text, string id)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            var existing = store.GetFileNames(string.Format(Prefix + "/*-{0}.dat", id));
            if (existing.Any()) return; //it already is saved

            string name = string.Format(Prefix + "/{0}-{1}.dat", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff"), id);
        tryagain:
            bool doover=false;
            try
            {
                AttemptFileWrite(store, name, text);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                doover = true;
            }
            catch (IsolatedStorageException) //THIS LINE
            {
                doover = true;
            }
            if (doover)
            {
                Attempt(() => store.DeleteFile(name)); //because apparently this can also fail. 
                var files = store.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(Prefix, "*.dat"));
                foreach (var file in files.OrderBy(x=>x))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        store.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(Prefix, file));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                goto tryagain; //prepare the velociraptor shield!
            }
        }
    }

    void AttemptFileWrite(IsolatedStorageFile store, string name, string text)
    {
        using (var file = store.OpenFile(
            name,
            FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.ReadWrite,
            FileShare.None | FileShare.Delete
            ))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                writer.Write(text);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }

    static void Attempt(Action func)
    {
        try
        {
            func();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    static T Attempt<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return default(T);
    }
    public string GetSaved()
    {

        string content=null;
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            var files = store.GetFileNames(Path.Combine(Prefix,"*.dat")).OrderBy(x => x);

            if (!files.Any()) return new MessageBatch();
            foreach (var filename in files)
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream file=null;
                try
                {
                    file = Attempt(() =>
                        store.OpenFile(Path.Combine(Prefix, filename), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None | FileShare.Delete));
                    if (file == null)
                    {
                        continue; //couldn't open. assume locked or some such
                    }
                    file.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
                    {
                        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    //take note here. We delete the file, while we still have it open!
                    //This is done because having the file open prevents other readers, but if we close it first,
                    //then there is a race condition that right after closing the stream, another reader could pick it up and 
                    //open exclusively. It looks weird, but it's right. Trust me. 
                    store.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(Prefix, filename));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (file != null) file.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return content;
    }
```

At the line marked THIS LINE, is what I'm talking about. When doing AttemptFileWrite, I can look over at `store.AvailableSpace` and see that there is enough room to fit the data into it, but upon trying to open the file, it throws this IsolatedStorageException with the description of `Operation Not Permitted`. Aside from this weird case, in all other cases it's just an IOException thrown with a message about the disk being full

I'm trying to figure out if I have some odd race condition, or if this is an error I just have to deal with or what?

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Like many other fun things in Windows Phone land, this won't work as you expect. I believe this is because the operating systems caches fileops for performance reasons (as it sees fit) but doesn't always commit them right away. Therefore, to your app, the file is deleted, but the drive is still physically full.

Comment: @PatrickF so, what's the best course of action? Do a `Thread.Sleep` for a bit before retrying the write?

Comment: Sleeping on threads is a big no no. I don't know that there is a way to force a flush either. You probably need to just change the approach. What I do in those cases is simply to not rely on exceptions at all. Check for available space, but give yourself some head room (don't use more than 90% of what's available, depending on the size of your files) and you'll always have the wiggle room you need.

Comment: @PatrickF that's actually harder to implement somewhat, because of race conditions and the drive possibly becoming full outside of our control. This should be an *extreme* edge case, so I think Thread.Sleep is good enough in this case as well.

Comment: Yeah it all comes down to how you approach the problem once you understand why it behaves the way it does.